# BPEL and ESB: SOA Overview

Tags: wsdl, soa, rules, bpel

I am studying SOA architecture and I am bit confused, googling there are many definition of that, many technologies are involved and here my doubts start:
If I got correctly these are the principles for a system to be SOA:

1. Use Open Standard: XML, WSDL, WS Security. About WSDL, it is important because integrating different services (typically  Web Services must expose them contract? Then If I got BPEL usage is just a process that uses contract of services to permit communication between them.
2. Be Modular
3. Use ESB : (This seems to be a must, even for services that don't
   need to communicate via it.. This introduces my first doubts.. if a
   service is exposed as Web Service expose his own WSLD that enables
   interoperability, **why the ESB should be used as a must**?
4. Then comes BPEL, **is BPEL a language to orchestrate services
   interaction each other**? Something like Orchestration in Saga
   Pattern?
5. Increase interworking between services as much as possible
   (different than the principles of Microservice Architecture)
6. Adopting previous (old) enterprise application that usually are very
   old, a SOA is frequently based on services using
   traditional relational database

Maybe point 5 and 6 are consequences than rules to follow...
Tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can try to answer to my question:
**About the usage of ESB**: In theory it could be possible to avoid the usage of ESB, but without an ESB application owners would each have to find their own unique way to expose service interfaces, which is a lot of work (even if the interfaces are eventually reusable) and creates a significant maintenance challenge in the future, that's why it is considered essential part of a SOA and considered such a de facto element of any SOA implementation.

**BPEL**: yes, it is used to orchestrate and coordinate different exposed API, maybe from different Web Services to create a new application.

Comment: To further expand on what you have written, ESB are purpose built to connect almost any application and has the capability of exposing any backend as an API. Having a ESB enables an enterprise to keep the connectivity logic outside of its core applications that run the business logic. This helps increasing the stamina of your core applications with ESB managing the data routing, orchestration, data enrichment, wrapping application logic as web services. Most ESB vendors have inbuilt code to connect to ERP/CRM/MQ/API's and also have graphical mapping which significantly speeds up development.